# How can Ember Rails templates be kept from leaking into the browser?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ember.js

I'm considering a switch from AngularJS to Ember as the frontend framework for a couple of Rails apps that I'm working with. But the thing that's making me a little antsy involves how and when template HTML is sent to the browser.

With Angular, I would typically set up a Rails endpoint like `/api/v1/foo` such that calling `foo.html` would render out a template and calling `foo.json` would render out its data; and if I wanted to protect `foo`, I would place the whole endpoint behind a `before_action :some_auth_method` filter, effectively barring unauthorized access to both the template *and* the data.

With Ember, it *looks* as though the precompiled Handlebars templates are all sent to the browser in one big chunk, such that a nefarious visitor could easily see what they look like---denuded of data, it's true, but I'm still not sure that I'm comfortable having even vague details about the app's inner workings leaked to every Tom, Dick, and Hacky who happens along.

So my first question, of course, is: Am I missing something? And if I'm not, then: Is there any way around this behavior?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No you're not missing anything, that is how Ember works out of the box. Is there a way around that behavior? Probably. But before you try to work around it, you should seriously consider whether it's really worth it or not. Do you *really* care if somebody has the HTML template for your site? If your security is set up right, you shouldn't care. But if you do care, here's what I might do:

1. Set up routes on your server to check for access to routes on the client.
2. Set up a way to send your templates from your server to the client. I would either send the precompiled template and then use `eval()` to get the function, or send the HTML and use the Handlebars compiler to compile it on the client side.
3. If your `beforeModel` hook of the route, check for access to the route. If the user has access, get the template, store it in `Ember.TEMPLATES` then let the user in. If the user doesn't have access, redirect them elsewhere.

You don't have many details in your question, so I can't get more specific, but something like this would allow you to load your templates asynchronously as they're needed. There's a similar discussion [on the Ember forum](http://discuss.emberjs.com/t/asynchronous-template-loading/3274).

Comment: Thanks so much, for the answer, for the forum link, and for the gentle suggestion that I might be overthinking it! I very much appreciate all three, and I look forward to digging into the resources you provided.